# AbstractMethodError when overriding a Java method with vararg parameter from Scala

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions

I need to override a Java method from a Java interface which makes use of a vararg parameter:

```
public interface Function<T> {
    T apply(Object... var1);
}
```

When I try to implement the method apply in Scala like follows

```
class ScalaFunction extends Function[String] {

  override def apply(args: Object*): String = args.toList match {
    // impl
  }

}
```

I get a "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null" error during run-time.

This is what I already tried:

1. using `@varargs args` Scala annotation which should generate a Java-friendly delegate method => resulted in the same error
2. using a self-provided delegate method

   def apply(args: Array[Object]): Unit = apply(args: _*)

   which was actually successfully called, but I'm not able to use    String as return type because then the compiler yields a

> Error:(13, 7) double definition: def apply(args: Array[Object]):
>   String at line 20 and override def apply(args: AnyRef*): String at
>   line 13 have same type after erasure: (args: Array[Object])String

The calling Java code looks like this:

```
Object[] args = //...
Object returnValue = function.apply(args);
```

Any ideas?

See this Gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/mrueegg/f191e547bee6a24a6bcf

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: No solution (sorry) but have you tried getting your IDE to override the method for you? I would imagine it's a standard process and they should do it correctly for you.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: IntelliJ suggests override def apply(objects: AnyRef*): String = ??? which is what I already have...

Comment: Can't reproduce this on Scala 2.11.6 - what version are you on?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that: Scala 2.11.7

Comment: did you use the interface type (Function) to call apply or the implementation (ScalaFunction)?

Comment: "using a self-provided delegate method" you could just give it a different name.

Comment: I don't think so. Because that is the method that is called by function.apply(args) above. Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue.](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9013) I haven't followed it closely, but maybe someone wants to add info.

Comment: Thanks, this must be the right issue I think. By the way, with my Gist from above I was able to verify that it worked with Scala 2.10.4 while I now get a java.lang.AbstractMethodError with Scala 2.11.7!

Comment: I'd at least comment on the ticket with the test case. Or maybe ask on gitter.